# What are necessary and sufficient conditions for the natural map between a polynomial ring and the set of polynomial functions to be injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is a commutative ring (with unity), $R[X]$ is the polynomial ring, and $R^R$ is the set of $R$-valued functions on $R$, then there is a natural homomorphism of $R$-algebras which sends every polynomial $P$ in $R[X]$ to the polynomial function in $R^R$ that maps $r \mapsto P(r)$.

I want to know if there are any necessary and sufficient conditions that $R$ must satisfy in order for this homomorphism to be injective. In other words, for which rings is it true that if one knows *all* the values of a polynomial function, then one can uniquely determine the polynomial’s coefficients?

So far I have been able to determine that:

1. If $R$ is a zero ring, then $R[X]$ and $R^R$ are singletons and the homomorphism is *always* injective.
2. If $R$ is a finite, nonzero ring, we have $R = \{r_1, \dots, r_n\}$, where $n \geq 2$, and $0 \neq 1$, and $(X - r_1) \cdot \dots \cdot (X - r_n)$ is a nonzero polynomial which is sent to the zero function in $R^R$. Thus, the homomorphism is *never* injective.
3. If $R$ is an infinite ring, then $R$ being an integral domain is a *sufficient* condition for the homomorphism to be injective, since any polynomial with coefficients in an integral domain will have finitely many roots.

However, I cannot come up with any condition on $R$ in the case that $R$ is a infinite ring (not necessarily an integral domain) which is equivalent to this $R$-algebra homomorphism being injective.

Comment: The condition of being injective is itself necessary and sufficient.  That is a pedantic answer, but what you are seeking is not just a necessary and sufficient condition, but an *interesting* one.

Comment: The answer here covers reduced indecomposable rings: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268734/do-there-exist-nonzero-identically-vanishing-polynomials-over-infinite-or-chara

Comment: can we rule out characteristic $0$ rings using the following? suppose $f$ is in the kernel of the map you have described , let $f = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0$, considering any distinct $n+1$ integers different from $1$, we see that the vectors $(a_n,\cdots,a_0)$ is killed by a Vandermont matrix, which implies this vector is $0$ and hence $f = 0$.

Comment: @Dave Also linked to that question is this one which is strikingly similar to my own question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160986/rings-for-which-no-polynomial-induces-the-zero-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @skeptic I agree with your example, but why must the integers be different from $1$?

Comment: @shoteyes .. you are right .. you don't need it ..

Comment: Actually, the ring being of characteristic $0$ is not sufficient. From one of the links, $\mathbb{Z}[a, b]/(a^2, ab, 2a)$ is of characteristic $0$, however all elements are roots of $aX(X - 1)$. The problem in the Vandermonde argument is that the determinant may be a zero divisor.

Comment: @shoteyes .. yes.. right